# Can't upload a file in a cypress test that requires Google Cloud authentication in CI

Tags: google-cloud-storage, cypress, github-actions

I'm testing file upload to Google Cloud using Cypress in CI. I'm using the [Authenticate to Google Cloud github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/authenticate-to-google-cloud) to authenticate and credentials are successfully created. When the cypress test attempts upload, however, I receive the following error: `1. Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started for more information.`

This is the code for CI:

```
e2e:
    needs: ["docker-build", "install-dev-tools"]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: dev env setup
        uses: ./.github/actions/dev-env-setup
      # - name: Setup tmate session
      #   uses: mxschmitt/action-tmate@v3
      #   with:
      #     detached: true
      - name: run app locally
        uses: ./.github/actions/local-app-run
      - id: "auth"
        name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v1"
        with:
          export_environment_variables: true
          workload_identity_provider: ${{secrets.IDENTITY_PROVIDER}}
          service_account: ${{secrets.GCS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}}
      - name: run e2e tests
        env:
          CYPRESS_TEST_INTERNAL_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.TEST_INTERNAL_USERNAME }}
          CYPRESS_TEST_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TEST_INTERNAL_PASSWORD }}
          CYPRESS_TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.TEST_ADMIN_USERNAME }}
          CYPRESS_TEST_ADMIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TEST_ADMIN_PASSWORD }}
          CYPRESS_TEST_UNAUTHORIZED_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.TEST_UNAUTHORIZED_USERNAME }}
          CYPRESS_TEST_UNAUTHORIZED_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.TEST_UNAUTHORIZED_PASSWORD }}
          HAPPO_API_KEY: ${{ secrets.HAPPO_API_KEY }}
          HAPPO_API_SECRET: ${{ secrets.HAPPO_API_SECRET }}
          TEST_ENV: "test"
          CYPRESS_GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}}
          CYPRESS_ATTACHMENTS_BUCKET: ${{secrets.ATTACHMENTS_BUCKET}}
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS}}
          ATTACHMENTS_BUCKET: ${{secrets.ATTACHMENTS_BUCKET}}
        run: |
          echo $CYPRESS_GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
          echo $TEST_ENV
          echo $ATTACHMENTS_BUCKET
          echo $CYPRESS_ATTACHMENTS_BUCKET
          pwd
          yarn test:e2e
        working-directory: ./app
```

PR code is here: https://github.com/bcgov/cas-cif/pull/1825

I initially thought the problem was with the authenticate action or `env` variables, but when I log the `env` variables in the cypress test they're all available.